# Python I want to print the text from printer but I want to be in the middle of the paper

Tags: python, printing

as can be understood from the title, I want to print a .txt file from the printer so that it is in the middle of the page. I know this is possible with the win32printer library but when I read the documentation I couldn't find an exact setting for it, which margin values ​​will help me to center the text exactly? Or is there a preset setting for my averaging?

```
from win32printing import Printer

with Printer(linegap=1) as printer:
    printer.text("title1", font_config=font)
```

I tried to do with margin settings but cant find a exact solution

Answer (score 0):

With the actual win32printing, you can change the alignment of each text with the attribute "align" to "left", "right" and "center", see the next example"

```
from win32printing import Printer

font= {
    "height": 35,
    "faceName":'Consolas',
}

with Printer(linegap=1,margin=(200,250,50,0), auto_page=True) as printer:
    printer.text("title1", font_config=font, align='left')
```

Now, when you need vertical center, you have to edit the file win32printing.py  because it is not defined (see its definition).

Inside the file, there is a class named "get_print_flag". Please edit as it follows (more info https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawtext):

```
@classmethod
def get_print_flag(cls, align="left"):
    print_flag = win32con.DT_TOP|win32con.DT_WORDBREAK|win32con.DT_NOCLIP
    if align == "left":
        print_flag |= win32con.DT_LEFT
       #Add this line to have left-center option        
    elif align == "left-center":
            print_flag |= win32con.DT_LEFT|win32con.DT_SINGLELINE|win32con.DT_VCENTER
    elif align == "center":
            print_flag |= win32con.DT_CENTER
    elif align == "right":
            print_flag |= win32con.DT_RIGHT
    return print_flag
```